# How to use variable as the pattern for http.HandleFunc()

Tags: http, go

I have some HTTP requests that share a lot of common functions:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "mypackage"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/myurl1", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        mypackage.Common()
        mypackage.Different1()
    })
    http.HandleFunc("/myurl2", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        mypackage.Common()
        mypackage.Different2()
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Could I use a variable in the place of `/myurl` and use a switch case to reduce my code repetition, like this:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "mypackage"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc(variable string, func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

         mypackage.Common()

         switch variable {
         case "myurl1":
             mypackage.Different1()
         case "myurl2":
             mypackage.Different2()
         }
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Comment: hi, is this what you want to do ? https://play.golang.org/p/Sk-12yywmbU

Comment: `http.ServeMux` aims to be simple, but most any 3rd part router will allow you to map path placeholders to variables in some way.

Comment: @PajriAprilio thanks, this is what I was aiming to do

Comment: @PedroVieira no problem. i'll move it to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can route to / first then call Different1 or Different2 based on the path. Please refer to [this](https://play.golang.org/p/Sk-12yywmbU) code.